# Sublime Editor 4 won't compile simple C/C++ code

Tags: installation, sublimetext

I've installed Sublime Editor 4 and GCC (MinGW, added to PATH)

Sublime refuses to compile any C/C++ code, and gives this strange "un-googleble" error:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6W8L.png)

I tried to create "Build Systems", that I found in guides, nothing changed.

Edit: If I try to just paste command in cmd, result is:

```
    C:\Windows\system32>gcc "C:\Users\Hamburger\Documents\My Scripts\C\SublimeTest\main.c" -o "C:\Users\Hamburger\Documents\My Scripts\C\SublimeTest\main"
    gcc: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory
```

Files and directories are there.

Also tried simpler filepath:

```
C:\Windows\system32>gcc "C:\test\main.c" -o "C:\test\main"
gcc: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory
```

Comment: What happens when you try to run that command from the command line?

Comment: Edited it. I'm going to try moving file to a simple file path (like "C:\test\main.c") and running again